# How to show top rated items into another activity using Custom ListView when using Rating Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have made an Android Rating Bar program to accept user rating, calculate the total ratings and display it in indicator rating bar.

Now i want to add two more functionalities in my Rating Bar program:

1. I want to use my existing Rating Bar in ListView
2. Secondly want to show high to low rated rating items in another activity like MyRatings

My Java Code:-

```
public class InteractiveRatingBarActivity extends Activity implements
OnRatingBarChangeListener {
RatingBar getRatingBar;
RatingBar setRatingBar;
TextView countText;
int count;
float curRate;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewsById();

    setRatingBar.setRating(curRate);
    getRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
}  

private void findViewsById() {
    getRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.getRating);
    setRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.setRating);
    countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countText);
}

public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar rateBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    curRate = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format((curRate * count + rating)
            / ++count));
    Toast.makeText(InteractiveRatingBarActivity.this,
            "New Rating: " + curRate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setRatingBar.setRating(curRate);
    countText.setText(count + " Ratings");
}
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/getRating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/setRating"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/getRating"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getRating"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setRating"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you facing problems?

Comment: @Luksprog, I don't know how to show top to low rated items into another activity using listview, like in above code i am not using listview but simply calculating number of Reviews has given yet, but very frankly not storing in anything, so please help me to show some code and give some direction to achieve that target

Comment: Well, you don't have anything to rate, no object no nothing so try to explain better and give more information about what `items` to rate. A `ListView` with sorted ratings is easy to make you need to make a custom adapter.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks i will try that then tomorrow get back to you..bye for now..

Comment: You should have to save them in an arraylist or hashmap,... and pass that variable (ie using a StaticClass to mantain variables between different activites/classes) or (depending the case) create a method to do that in the caller Activity (pass the activity as parameter of the listviewadapter) and use the same method or another of the Activity to sort the listview and refresh it.